# Jersey JUnit Test Framework - Error Status 500

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

I want to test my jersey 1 -application with the jersey test [framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/test-framework.html).

I want to test this:

```
@Path("fieldgen")
public class VRApi {

@Path("/testCon")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testCon() {

    return "testcon";
}

@Path("/getTestObj")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TestObj getField() {

    TestObj tobj= new TestObj ("str1", "str2", "str3");
    return tobj;
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
public class TestMB extends JerseyTest{

private WebResource webResource = resource();

public TestMB() throws Exception {
    super("...api...");
}

@Test
public void testCon() {

    String responseMsg = webResource.path("/fieldgen/testCon").get(String.class);
    assertEquals("testcon", responseMsg);       
}


@Test
public void getTestObj()  {

    WebResource.Builder mbRes = webResource.path("/fieldgen/getTestObj").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    TestObj vr = mbRes.get(TestObj.class);

    assertEquals(vr, new TestObj("str1", "str2", "str3"));
}
```

The first test is okay. 
Second test fails:

```
  A message body writer for Java class modelVR.TestObj, and Java type class 
  modelVR.TestObj, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

I also tried to use the ClientResponse.
POM dep.:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whats the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing "jackson-databind" which includes the automatic POJO to JSON and reverse mapper. (Maybe the name is slightly different in Jackson 1.x)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have registered the Pojo Mapping feature in the client as explained in jersey docs [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html). The relevant snippet is given below.

```
 ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
 clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
 Client client = Client.create(clientConfig)
```